# How to get specific element of decoded Json in yii 1?

Tags: php, json, yii, yii1.x

I have following code:

```
    public function actionsdf($id){
        $dsf=UserLog::model()->findByPk($id);
        $decode=$dsf->text;
        var_dump($decode=$dsf->text);
        $res=CJSON::decode($decode);
        var_dump($res);

    }
```

The result of `var_dump($decode=$dsf->text);`is

`string(103) "{"text":"LOG_EVENT_MEMBERSHIP_FORM_SENT {time}{form_id}","params":{"{time}":"11:38","{form_id}":"402"}}"`

and the result of decoded json(`var_dump($res);)`is

`array(2) { ["text"]=> string(46) "LOG_EVENT_MEMBERSHIP_FORM_SENT {time}{form_id}" ["params"]=> array(2) { ["{time}"]=> string(5) "11:38" ["{form_id}"]=> string(3) "402" } }`

I need to retrieve only `402`itself from form_d(where form_id=402). How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be ["params"]["{form_id}"]

```
    $res=CJSON::decode($decode);
    var_dump($res);

    var_dump( $res["params"]["{form_id}"] );
```